# Rails: Route for :collection that is both GET *and* POST?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, post, get, routes

I have a route that currently looks like this:

```
map.resources :regions, :collection => {:select_for_payroll => :get}, has_one => :payroll
```

How can I make the :select_for_payroll take both GET *and* POST?

Many thanks!

MrM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! Here:

```
map.resources :regions, 
 :collection => {:select_for_payroll => [:get, :post]}, 
     has_one => :payroll
```